# VLookup Merge in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I have two df's with a common key, "API". I want to "VLookup" the "API" and fill in the column with the corresponding answer. I am confused on how to utilize the `merge` to mimic a VLookup.

```
col_1 = ['Route', 'API', 'Owner']
data_1 = [['', '123456', ''],
          ['', '789123', ''],
          ['', '456789', ''],
          ['', '256709', '']
         ]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_1, columns=col_1)

col_2 = ['Name', 'Route', 'API', 'Owner']
data_2 = [['Hay', 'Route 12', '789123', 'Jon Doe'],
          ['Pirate', 'Route 03', '123456', 'Mary Smith'],
          ['Oat', 'Route 01', '256709', 'Jane Vick'],
          ['Pop', 'Route 04', '456789', 'Jack Roe']
         ]
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=data_2, columns=col_2)
```

So `df1` has empty columns that need to be filled based off the API match in `df2`. What I've tried is the following

```
df1 = df2.merge(df2, on='API')
```

or

```
df1 = df2.merge(df2, on='API', how='outer')
```

I've switched the `how` to use `'inner', 'right', 'left'`
But all methods create new columns, instead of just filling in the blank already existing columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `merge`, use it like this:

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, on='API')[['Route_y','API','Owner_y']].rename(columns={'Route_y':'Route','Owner_y':'Owner'})
```

**Output:**

```
      Route     API       Owner
0  Route 03  123456  Mary Smith
1  Route 12  789123     Jon Doe
2  Route 04  456789    Jack Roe
3  Route 01  256709   Jane Vick
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it without merge. `isin` does the lookup

`df2[df1['API'].isin(df2['API'])].drop(['Name'], axis=1)`

```
      Route     API       Owner
0  Route 12  789123     Jon Doe
1  Route 03  123456  Mary Smith
2  Route 01  256709   Jane Vick
3  Route 04  456789    Jack Roe
```